# I use graphql codegen. When I use query and mutation in the same .tsx file, data changed in real time. How?

Tags: graphql-codegen

I use graphql codegen. When I use query and mutation in the same .tsx file, data changed in real time. I didn't write something subscription query and states or something. How does it work?

Please explain it if there is someone who knows about it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.